# NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure() after Maven integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, pom.xml, nosuchmethoderror

I am building REST web services using Spring Hibernate with Maven integration.
My POM.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SocialNetwork</groupId>
    <artifactId>SocialNetwork</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
        <version>3.8.1</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
    <!-- Spring framework -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure()Lorg/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration;
at main.java.com.pretech.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
at main.java.com.pretech.dao.LoginDao.checkLogin(LoginDao.java:46)
at main.java.com.pretech.util.Util.checkAuthentication(Util.java:12)
at main.java.com.pretech.AboutUsController.getAboutUs(AboutUsController.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
[...]
```

Comment: `Aug 11, 2014 11:28:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.0.GA
Aug 11, 2014 11:28:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.6
Aug 11, 2014 11:28:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 11, 2014 11:28:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Aug 11, 2014 11:28:00 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling`

Comment: Which Spring/Hibernate version do you use?
Which Java version? 
It seems that the versions are mixed up!

Comment: @Tobiask i am using jre 5, Spring 3.2 & hibernate-annotation-3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed two different versions of Hibernate in your pom.xml.

Totally drop the Hibernate dependencies you are using and simply use

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I would urge you however to use the latest version of Hibernate if possible

Comment: i ahve removed the dependency 3.5.6-Final. but now on maven-install i am getting the following error : `package org.hibernate does not exist`

Comment: i have added the dependency   `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>` but again the same excption appears.

Comment: Same Exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure()Lorg/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration;`

Comment: i have used the same dependency that you have mentioned. but still the same Exception

Comment: Have you seen my updated answer? Also, have you performed a maven clean?

Comment: yes i have seen your updated answer and then maven clean

Comment: Do you have any other hibernate dependencies in your pom?

Comment: No the whole POM file i have already post in my question.. the only change i have made is added dependency suggested by you and removed   `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: But in my lib folder of web-inf i have hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar & hibernate-annotations-3.3.0.jar files.  as i am converting my project to maven i am using POM.xml now

Comment: You need to remove all the hibernate 3 dependencies

Comment: thanks for your rep;ies @geoand I have removed all hibernate 3 dependencies from lib folder. now i am getting new exception   :  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration`

Comment: That class does not exist in hibernate 4. Are you sure you cleared all the hibernate 3 dependencies? Can you sshow how you are configuring it?

Comment: You were right geoand, there was still a jar of hibernate 3 present in  lib folder, i removed it . AnnotationConfiguration class is depricated in hibernate 4. i replaced it from configuration. it solved my problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this dependency in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0.GA</version></dependency>
```

After clean, install it'll work